# converting the string from an EditText into an integer causes application stop-working before it starts

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, gettext

I am working on a code and the part of converting the string into and integer as shown above is causing the application to stop working before it starts when I upload it to the mobile.
I have reduced the code as minimum as possible. the following code is giving the exact same problem. What would the solution be?

```
  String no=edttxt.getText().toString();       //this will get a string
  int no2=Integer.parseInt(no);              //this will get a no from the
```

**This is my code:**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView txtview;
    EditText edttxt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    edttxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

    String no=edttxt.getText().toString();       //this will get a string
    int no2=Integer.parseInt(no);              //this will get a no from the string

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            txtview.setText(edttxt.getText());
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be getting a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` because as soon as the app starts you are getting the string from edittext in `onCreate()`. This would return `""` which would cause the exception in the line `Integer.parseInt()`. Depending on your use case for `no2`, you need to move it accordingly.

Comment: Something like this int no2 = 0; try { no2 = Integer.parseInt(no); } catch (Exception e){}

Comment: @Aloweiwi Like this^? If yes, then just change `Exception` to `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: great, it stopped crashing, but what should I put inside the brackets {}?

Comment: @Aloweiwi Your code within `{}` will be called when an exception scenario occurs. In these cases, you don't want your program to halt [further]. You can put `no2 = 0;` here so it has a default value in case of exceptions or show a toast message saying *"wtf! enter a number here"* to the user. Most  developers also put a `e.printStackTrace();` here which would log the entire error log and helps in debugging. However, you can even leave it blank. Totally your choice.

Comment: I tried to put this  "public static int no2;" at the beginning. 
but it seems it doesn't make "no2" accessible from other classes. does it?

Comment: @Aloweiwi A `public static` variable shall be accessible from other classes.

Comment: @Shaishav That's why I am asking, I have made a "public static int no2=1000;", but each time I am getting the 1000 value not the value from the editbox

Comment: Ok...Since you are getting the value that means it's accessible. Now, notice where are you updating its value...If only in the `onCreate()`...then you won't get the latest value entered by the user...try to set its value on a button click or right when you are switching to a different activity (this depends on your use-case)